# Codeigniter blog application: target the single post view from another view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

I have added Facebook's open graph meta tags to the website's header.

The line `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/posts/' . $post->post_image); ?>">` however, only applies to the single post.

The problem is that, since the `header` view is common to all the pages (URLs) in the website, I need to target the single post view with an if statement of the kind: if Posts controller and single post page.

Or, alternatively, if single post route.

Considering that the single post method in the Posts controller is:

```
public function post($slug) {
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->sidebar_posts($limit=5, $offset=0);
    $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($slug);

    if ($data['categories']) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
            $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
        }
    }

    if (!empty($data['post'])) {
        // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
        $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;

        // Get post comments
        $post_id = $data['post']->id;
        $data['comments'] = $this->Comments_model->get_comments($post_id);

        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('post');
    } else {
        $data['tagline'] = "Page not found";
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('404');
    }
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}
```

what is the best method to target the single post view?

Comment: you sort of answered your own question. add an if statement in the header view

Comment: @Alex An that if statement could be *if what*, in code terms. I do not know how to "translate" *if single post* in... code.

Comment: well it would be in view `if (isset($post->post_image))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($post->post_image)) {
    // og image
}
```

as the image will (or so it seems) only be available when it is a single post.

similarly you could add a variable like `$data['single_post'] = true` and just use that to determine if the `og:image` is applicable. this method would also require an `isset` e.g. `if (isset($single_post) && $single_post))` as it might not be defined elsewhere.